# Saving and parsing rules for rules based agent in Wumpus World

Tags: c#

I'm writing a rules based agent to solve an extended version of the Wumpus World game. What I'd like to do is allow the user to set his own rules, save them ( in a XML file) and load them when he wants.
Is there a way to apply those rules in C# in a "easy" way, or I have to parse every single rule and "translate" it inside of my program? 
And about the saving part, a XML file is good enought or it's better to save a "working" version of user rules?